# Delete special character, specific texts and blank lines in .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this .txt file where there is a special character which looks strange('uparrow', see screenshot).
How do I remove this and blank lines along with unnecessary repeated header rows after few rows.
My attempt -

```
remove_text = ['Trial Balance - Total Currency', 'Page:', 'Currency:', 'Balance Type:', 'ENTITY Range:', 'Ledger:', 'ENTITY:', '------------', '']


with open('MICnew.txt') as oldfile, open('MICnew.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in remove_text):
            newfile.write(line)

with open('MICnew.txt','r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        if not line.isspace():
            file.write(line)
```

My codes delete few unnecessary text and their lines but does not delete THE special char and blank lines

[image: Screenshot of text file]

Comment: I think the oldfile should be different from newfile in the 1st ```with``` clause, because if you open newfile as write mode, it just deletes the file's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me -

```
     open('MICnew.txt', 'w') as newfile:

    for line in oldfile:
        clean_line = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', ' ', line.strip('\x0c'))
        if not clean_line.isspace():
            newfile.write(clean_line)
```

I was able to arrive at this solution by using suggestions from community members in my other [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999080/replace-an-arrow-character-repeating-headers-and-blank-lines-in-text-file-and-p)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete any non-ascii character with the following:

```
cleaned_string = string_to_clean.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode()
```

Comment: I tried this 

```with open('MIC.txt') as oldfile, open('MICnew.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:        
        line = line.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode()
        newfile.write(line)```

But it did not delete the arrow char. Any thing I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use regex to get rid of any unessecary characters.

```
import re
with open('MICnew.txt') as oldfile, open('MICnew.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        newfile.write(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z_0-9\s]','',line))
```

Comment: Thanks but this will not solve my problem.